# Visual studio 2012 and entity framework 6.0.2 - some async methods are missing?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012 and I've installed entity framework 6.0.2 via Nuget Package Manager Console. I am using database first pattern.. I know that EF 6.0.2 has 'LoadAsync', 'ToListAsync', 'SingleOrDefaultAsync', etc. methods but VS 2012 IDE shows only 'SaveChangesAsync' and 'FindAsync' methods.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

in your code?